# How to divide large amount of tasks into small ones and execute in particular interval,in php

Tags: php

I need to send a common mail to a large number of members (example 5000 members).

I need to send this using SMTP server.

I will get this 5000 members mail id  from Data base.

New members will add to the Data base  table in each hour ,

for example

after 1 hour , the number of members will reach to 6000

So Which is the best method to send mail to all these members, by dividing the task

Answer (score 0):

You need a message broker. http://www.rabbitmq.com/ or http://www.zeromq.org/ will help you.

Comment: Any particular reason to pick either? Adding a short summary of both will improve your answer. Note that link-only answers are usually frowned upon.

Comment: You're right but I just wanted him to have notice of message brokers. I'm not a message broker tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a way to keep track of members that have been mailed (boolean on database table for example), create a script that sends a mail to X people, and configure a cron to execute this script every Y time.

If the increase of the number of members does not slow down and matches your example you will need to configure the script and cron to output more than 1000 messages an hour (say, if the script sends 100 messages it should run more than 10 times an hour, so about 1 every 5 minutes).

If the increase of the number of members progressively slows down then it comes down to how big a window of time do you have to ensure all members have received the mail.

Alternative, use a message broker like Ogun suggested.

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply.
Let me know 'Shell' has any relevance in this context

Answer (score 0):

How about to run it through asynchronous with curl.
This way, although you loop for 6000 members, your file won't get timeout response due to long time execution.

```
function send($params) {
    foreach($params as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    rtrim($fields_string,'&');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'http://localhost/anotherfiletosendemail.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($params));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```